# pushRegistry PKPushRegistry pushCredentials delegate method not called after PKPushRegistry.init()

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, pushkit

We have a current AppStore app which we are in the process of updating to include VOIP functionality. We are utilising Apple PushKit.

The user currently has the current version of the app installed, and have already granted permission to allow push notifications.

We have updated the app, and the user will upgrade to this new app via the AppStore however we are experiencing the following issue.

In the AppDelegate we have the following:-

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, LocationServiceDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, PKPushRegistryDelegate {

    var voipRegistry:PKPushRegistry?

    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
        NSLog("pushRegistry:didUpdatePushCredentials:forType:")

        if (type != .voIP) {
            return
        }
        Shared.credentials = pushCredentials
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        voipRegistry = PKPushRegistry.init(queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        voipRegistry?.delegate = self
        voipRegistry?.desiredPushTypes = Set([PKPushType.voIP])
    }
}
```

The issue is, when we are calling `PKPushRegistry.init()` in the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` the delegate method `pushRegistry` is not being called.

What is odd is, if the phone is restarted, then the delegate method successfully gets called.

Does the new app need to explicitly ask for PushKit VOIP notification permissions or will the standard Push Notification permissions (which will be granted in the old version of the app) suffice ?

It may also be worth mentioning that the old codebase (the current AppStore version) is written in Objective-C and the new version of the App (which is actually the same Bundle Identifier) is written in Swift 4.0.

Comment: This isn't something we've seen at Twilio before, so not sure what's going on. Personally, I would try explicitly asking for the VOIP permissions as that is a different user experience and Apple would likely not want an app to upgrade from regular push to VOIP push without user consent. It's definitely weird that a restart makes a difference though.